# Alternative of UNION in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables which contains 5 unique cities each. I want all 10 cities but i don't want to use UNION. Is there any alternative for UNION.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM TABLE1
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM TABLE2
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `UNION`? `UNION` is the right tool for the job here. Why use a hammer to put a screw in, when you have a perfectly usable screwdriver too?

Comment: And if you're using `UNION`, you don't need `DISTINCT`. `UNION` eliminates duplicates anyway.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the *actual* problem? Why do you assume there's anything wrong with UNION? `SELECT CITY FROM TABLE1
UNION
SELECT CITY FROM TABLE2` will return only unique values

Comment: i was just looking for an alternative of UNION for knowledge only, although i have no any problem with it. It was just a learning.

Comment: Then the answer is "no", there isn't an alternative. `UNION` and `UNION ALL` fulfil specific functions. Even functions that fulfil similar roles are often different in some way. For example, `ISNULL` and `COALESCE` are often thought to be the very similar (or the same when using 2 parameters), but this really isn't the case. In fact, they can behave very differently. For example, `SELECT ISNULL('a',1);` and `SELECT COALESCE('a',1);`.. One generates an error, while the other does not.

Comment: there are alternatives, you can write query without UNION, but for this case UNION is just the best choice to go

Comment: There can be alternative ways to tackle particular problems, but when your problem to be solved is practically the poster child for using UNION, you can't expect any reasonable alternatives that don't just massively overcomplicate the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternate way

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.city is null then b.city else a.city end 
                         FROM Table1 FULL JOIN Table2b ON 1 = 0
```

it offers no advantage over UNION - but you might be interested in seeing FULL JOIN, which has its similarities to UNION

Comment: Thanks brother, that's what i was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You can apply Full Outer join instead of Union

```
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(t.City,t1.City)
FROM dbo.TABLE1 t
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.TABLE2 t1 ON t.City = t.City;
```

This query provides you the same result as union

Comment: Good lateral thinking!

Comment: @DB101 Thanks you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the data that you want into a temporary table and retrieve it from there. That will avoid the need for a UNION.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
INTO #City 
FROM TABLE1

INSERT INTO #City
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM TABLE2

SELECT DISTINCT City 
FROM #City
```

Comment: This won't work. `UNION` eliminates duplicates, this code doesn't. Even after checking for existing values it will simply do what `UNION` does in the most inefficient way possible - executing three queries instead of one and writing everything into tempdb when it could easily fit in memory

Comment: It's not the most inefficient way possible. You could use a cursor to iterate through each table and add one row at a time to the temp table... ;-)

Comment: I'm just fulfilling his spec ;)

Comment: You might want to add a "DISTINCT" to the final SELECT. You could get duplicates returned if there is any overlap of cities in TABLE1 and TABLE2 (although it doesn't sound like there is at the moment, you don't know if this might change in the future).

Answer (score 0):

If the first table is sure to contains all the records of the second table, then one can check if the id could be found inside a subquery with an `OR` clause.

I'm using an ORM framework which doesn't support the `UNION` operator (Apache OJB) and, with the above assumption, this strategy has proven to be faster than with the use of `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

For instance if the table STUDENT contains all the students of a province/state with a field for their current main school and another table, STUDENT_SECONDARY_SCHOOL, contains information for those students attending a second school part time, I can get the union of all students attending a particular school either full time or part time this way :

```
SELECT STD_ID FROM STUDENT 
WHERE 
    STD_SCHOOL='the_school' 
    OR 
    STD_ID IN (SELECT STD_ID FROM STUDENT_SECONDARY_SCHOOL WHERE STD_SCHOOL='the_school')
```

Again, I want to emphasize that this is **NOT** the equivalent of a `UNION` but can be useful in some situations.